# Synchronizing two tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I do not master SQL yet, and I'd like to do a specific synchronization of two tables:

- The synchronization should not occur in real time, it will be triggered.
- I have a text parameter to use (`username`) to extract the second table from a .txt
- The two tables have two common columns: one is the `id`, and the other is `write_date` as `timestamp without time zone`, representing the time of the last modification of the row. So given an id, and depending of the write_date, the first or the second row should be updated (the tables are not identical, and the processes are not symmetrical)
- I don't really know if I need to create a function, as I will probably call the update from something like "psql db_name < /path/to/script". I don't see how to pass my parameter that way though.

So I should do something like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updatedata(username TEXT) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    row
    data TEXT
    curtime timestamp without time zone := now();
BEGIN
    COPY table2 FROM '/path/to/data/directory' || username || '.txt' DELIMITER ';' CSV;
    FOR row IN
        SELECT table1.id,table1.data1,table2.data2 
        FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
        WHERE table1.write_date<table2.write_date
    LOOP
        --Process data
        UPDATE table1 SET data1 = data WHERE id = row.id;
        RETURN NEXT row;
    END LOOP;
    --Second FOR/LOOP
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

updatedata('user1');
```

Comment: If you want to "synchronize" the tables, why not just truncate the second table and then copy all the data from the first table into it.

Comment: I can't just copy the data because of compatibility: for example a character varying from the first table contains data for 3 columns of the second. The first table is also the database for all users, though it is not a problem with adding it in the where filter, that is also why I need the input parameter 'username'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you are using table2 as a temporary holding table.  In which case you should truncate it before use.  In order to update your main table, you do not need to do a loop, you can use a set-based solution instead.  You say that table1 data column has three columns from table2, so I assume you need to concatenate; in my example, I don't include a separator, but it is easy to add. What I think you need is something along the lines of:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updatedata(username TEXT) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    curtime timestamp without time zone := now();
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE table2;
    COPY table2 FROM '/path/to/data/directory' || username || '.txt' DELIMITER ';' CSV;
    UPDATE table1 t1 
        SET t1.data1 = t2.data1 || t2.data2 || t2.data3, t1.write_date = curtime
        FROM table2 t2 
        WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t1.username = $1 
        AND t1.write_date < t2.write_date;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

updatedata('user1');
```

Please note that this will only update existing records.  If new records exist in table2, they will not be added.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the advice with truncate, and the set-based solution!

Comment: My pleasure.  Please mark the question as answered.